# Is there an AWS Service Health page for govcloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The usual service health page http://status.aws.amazon.com/ doesn't include the govcloud domains.

I'm mostly seeing "what is govcloud" - type responses in Google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling "AWS GovCloud status" brings me to http://status.aws.amazon.com/govcloud

Comment: Choosing the right phrase makes all the difference. Thanks!

Comment: @LizH It also comes up if you put your question title into Google. :-p

Comment: OK, I'm just illiterate today then, no excuses.   (• ε •)